# Wicket 8 AnnotatedMountScanner not working anymore

Tags: wicket, wicket-8

After upgrading from Wicket 7 to Wicket 8, page mounting does not work anymore.

In Wicket 7 I added

```
new AnnotatedMountScanner().scanPackage("com.example").mount(this);
```

in my `init()` method of my `AuthenticatedWebApplication`
And on my page I added `@MountPath("/mypage")`.

In Wicket 8 this does not work anymore and instead of `/mypage` the browser URL points to `wicket/bookmarkable/com.example.MyPage` , however when I manually add
`mountPage("AAA", MyPage.class);` it works.

Here is my classpath with all wicket dependencies:

> $ mvn dependency:tree | grep wicket [INFO] +-
>
> org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-annotation:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] |  -
>   org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.apache.wicket:wicket-datetime:jar:8.0.0-M7:compile [INFO] +-
>   org.apache.wicket:wicket-auth-roles:jar:8.0.0:compile [INFO] +-
>   de.agilecoders.wicket:wicket-bootstrap-core:jar:2.0.2:compile [INFO]
>   |    +- de.agilecoders.wicket:jquery-selectors:jar:2.0.0:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars:wicket-webjars:jar:2.0.7:compile [INFO]
>   |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:jar:8.0.0:compile    [INFO]
>   +-    de.agilecoders.wicket:wicket-bootstrap-extensions:jar:2.0.2:compile
>   [INFO] +-
>   com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui-plugins:jar:8.0.0-M7:compile
>   [INFO] |  -
>   com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui-core:jar:8.0.0-M7:compile

But I do not want to add all mypages manually. Is it possible to also use the `AnnotatedMountScanner` again in Wicket 8?

Comment: Check whether you have two different Wicket versions on your classpath.

Comment: @svenmeier I added my classpath where you can see all wicket dependies. Looks acually quiet good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a class reloading issue with `spring-boot devtools`.
When `spring-boot-devtools` was added as dependency, the `RestartClassLoader` always changed the Page Classes and Wickets Page Class Matching was out of order.

Explanation after debugging.
When my BookmarkablePageLink called `getURL()` it went through normal Wicket processing of the RequestHandlers.

The crucial part began in the `AbstractBookmarkableMapper#382` where Wicket tries to find out by calling `checkPageClass` if the page class from the `RequestHandler` matches to the class of the `MountedMapper` internally represented via the `pageClassProvider`.

```
@Override
protected boolean checkPageClass(Class<? extends IRequestablePage> pageClass)
{
    return Objects.equals(pageClass, this.getPageClass());
}
```

As the objects were not the same (due to the use of `RestartClassLoader`) my bookmarkable page did not get the URL from the `MountedMapper`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.